# Create secondary FTP credentials on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have my credentials for access to the wwwroot directory on Azure App Service.

The question if is it possible to create others credentials that can access only in a subdirectory like wwwroot/subdirname

I tried to search in Deployment center but seems is possible only to reset credentials, not to create anothers.

Thanks

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is not supported, there some threads on Azure [Feedback1](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/34257331-access-specific-folder-in-azure-with-ftp) and [Feedback2](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/5467677-add-some-ftp-users) asking for this feature. Also according to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp), you can set user-level credentials that you can use for FTP/S login to **all App Service apps in your subscription**.